# iCloud Sync of Documents not recreating Folders on icloud.com. Process stuck. Catalina

Tags: mac, icloud, catalina

I have tried just about every solution available on the various boards and groups. Some so old they are no longer even relevant.
Photo syncing works.
iCloud Drive does not.
I'm running Catalina 10.15.2 with 2TB Cloud storage and plenty of spare space. Everything else is running like clockwork, except this iCloud Drive sync. It used to work! but sometime back it stopped. Last update perhaps?
however.

1. I have discovered that if I am to sync folders from the Documents folder on my Mac to the iCloud.com-> iCloud->Documents folder, I have to manually create the folder on iCloud, then go into that folder, and upload the file from my Mac's folder of the same name into the new folder on icloud.com. This is not right obviously.
2. I also see on my **Mac** that in the iCloud Drive folder, that sits in the Finder panel just above Documents, that the folder in question also appears in the iCloud Drive -> Documents -> Test Folder, along with any files that I put into that folder. So the Mac end is fine. It doesn't propagate up to icloud.com
3. The problem seems to be in two parts. Something is blocking the iCloud sync process from doing its job. The information at the bottom of the screen tells me that there is a massive amount of data and files waiting to upload - but it never happens.
   [image]
4. I can find no way of determining what files are causing the blockage. I am assuming that this blockage is also what is causing the process to not create new folders in which to put new files.
5. Finally - how can I restart the iCloud sync process and get it to update icloud.com correctly?
   Is there a non-destructive fix does anyone know?

EDIT:
Looking at

```
log show -v | grep cloudd
```

I'm seeing lots of Errors in the cloudd stream from bird.

```
bird: (CloudDocsDaemon) [com.apple.clouddocs:default] [ERROR] renameat(-1, '<private>', 23, '<private>', 4) failed after trying to fix permissions [17: File exists]
bird: (CloudDocsDaemon) [com.apple.clouddocs:default] [ERROR] -[BRCStageRegistry moveFromStage:toPath:fileName:error:]: (passed to caller) error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 UserInfo={NSDescription=<private>}
bird: (CloudDocsDaemon) [com.apple.clouddocs:default] [CRIT] UNREACHABLE: Failed to move from fault stage to live Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 UserInfo={NSDescription=<private>}
```

EDIT:
More information. If I drag an image into the Test Folder on iCloud.com 
it appears moments later on my Mac, in the iCloud -> Documents -> Test folder where it should be. But still, nothing is travelling the other way. Mac to iCloud.com

EDIT: 
Additional information. I did have SIP disabled. I enabled SIP again and had to grant permissions to a few stray legacy apps, but then noticed that cloudd and bird were driving relly hard CPU stats. I left the mac alone for an hour or so, and when I came back just now, the status bar of Finder no longer shows the Uploading 1185 items. It now shows only the current file selected, and space available on iCloud. So whatever happened when I re-enabled SIP seems to have cleared the backlog of uploadable files.
Has it solved the problem of files placed in Documents not being sent to the Cloud? It remains to be seen. I suspect perhaps not. I have three png files in a test folder on the Mac. I still only have 2 in the test folder I had to create by hand on the icloud.com folder.

Comment: In point 3 you say there is a massive amount of data **waiting** to be uploaded, but it shows that it has **already** uploaded 20.05GB of 20.05GB. It therefore seems to be unable fo finish the upload.

Comment: I find that info bar confusing anyway I must say. 141 items, What does that mean? Then 'uploading 1,185 items' (20.5 of 20.5) - Still uploading? Have been uploading? But in any case not being uploaded? But nothing telling me why anything being put into Documents or iCloud Drive on the Mac isn't being propagated up to icloud.com